# Which is correct "foremostly" or "foremost"

Tags: grammar

Given the following sentence: "[...], potential remedies rely *foremostly* on the replacement of unavailable features"

Is the usage of foremostly correct or should it be foremost? From a grammatical standpoint I can see that it is an adverb and should be *foremostly*, but from my feeling it has a weird sound to it. A quick Google search has revealed both versions in usage.

Would it be *foremost* if the sentence is expanded to "[...], potential remedies rely *first and foremost* on the replacement of unavailable features"?

Comment: From the full subscription-only OED: [**foremostly**](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/73098?redirectedFrom=foremostly#eid3757708) Derivatives  adv. Obsolete *in the foremost place, in front.* The normal word for your context is ***primarily***.

Comment: Foremost vs foremostly -  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foremostly%2Cforemost&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforemostly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforemost%3B%2Cc0 - curiously Merrian  Webster does not define foremostly  as obsolete https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foremostly